# Scripting the partition shrinking

Tags: scripting, partition, sfdisk

I have some disk image, taken with `dd if=/dev/somedevice of=filename.img`. I was able to shrink them following [this tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-BackUp-and-Shrink-Your-Raspberry-Pi-Image/).

Now I would like to script all the procedure, and I managed to perform almost everything, apart the fdisk resize part. I'm trying to resize the partition with this command

```
echo " , +7506944K," | sfdisk -N 2 /dev/loop14
```

But independently from the size I use I get an error:

```
/dev/loop14p2: Failed to resize partition #2.
```

How can i script the redefinition of the end of a partition? Why is my command failing, can I get some more information somehow?

Comment: The pipe is an automatic way to enter what you would have otherwise typed. Would running `sfdisk -N 2 /dev/loop14` and then typing from the keyboard `<space>,<space>+7506944K,` work?

Comment: Could you update with the partition table for `/dev/loop14`, and how will look after.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, I made some test using your method, and understood that the problem is the `+` sign. If I simply enter the size as 7506944K, without the plus it works. This obviously works also using the pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood what was wrong:

- First, `sfdisk` accept the size of the partition, not the increment, so the `+` sign is wrong. One difference from `fdisk` is that the end is the sector number from the beginning of the partition, not from the beginning of the device.
- Then the unit cannot be other than sectors.

So in my case, given the sector size of 512 bytes and a requested final size of approximately 7Gb , I had to launch the command as:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo " ,14596416" | sfdisk -N 2 /dev/loop14'
```

Comment: Units can be other than sectors, like size, see the reduce example [here](http://karelzak.blogspot.com/2015/05/resize-by-sfdisk.html). I don't know if you define the end sector or sectors from the start, I guess the latter.

Comment: @thanasisp have a look at the man page (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sfdisk.8.html), the unit option is deprecated and states that only sector is accepted. I don't think it's clear, if is just the unit option that is deprecated or the whole usage of the size inside the commands. Anyway I was not able to resize correctly until i moved to the sector size. For the end sector yes, it's the number of sectors from the start (i'll modify the answer)

Comment: If that worked for you, then it seems good (also there was a trailing comma into the question, I am sure you tried some size without it).